# SharePoint Importing data to MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, sharepoint

I am trying to import the data from SharePoint list, I have created one view of the fields required for my analysis.
I am facing a challenge in one of the field, while importing data. This is name picker field in Sharepoint.
When downloading the data in MS-Excel, this field, downloads as a string and giving the output like below (which is perfect):

```
Anne Bateman;#206
Meghan Mills;#3992
Maud Vreuls;#3915;Meghan Mills;#3992
```

But when i am trying to download the same view in MS-Access, this field is showing the output as (only numbers associated with names):

```
206
3992
3915,3992
```

and in design view this field is coming out to be "Number" datatype instead of string.

I am using below code for importing the data in MS-Access:

> > ```
> >  DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acImportSharePointList, "https://sharepointsitename.com/cms/AcctMgmtEnablers", _
> >     "Documents", _
> >     "{43C53B1F-98A3-4B2B-BF6C-7D81E75717C5}", _
> >     "Test"
> > ```

I need some help with importing this field as String and not letting MS Access to change it to number datatype.

Comment: Are you trying to set the data type of the ID or recover the Name field?

Comment: I am trying to recover the Name field, although its downloading but not in the proper format, as you can see above mentioned outputs in MS Access.

Comment: So the name and semi-colon are a part of the field value, not you separating columns? I think there's a sixth argument to the .TransferSharepointList that you could try setting to TRUE. That sometimes solves data type mismatches.

Comment: Why did the semi-colon change to a comma in the results? Is that a typo?

Comment: @Christopher D. : "#", ":", & Numbers are part of the field value and we are not separating them for now. I have tries the last argument to be "Yes", but no luck on it. I am not sure why access is converting it Comma while importing.

Comment: I can't find a good source, but my hunch is the "#" is a reserved character. It is for files/folders, etc but I can't find a source for a string. Could you remove the "#" to test? [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105992/which-special-characters-are-not-allowed-in-sharepoint-2013-files-folders)